# How to get value for the key from Spark Scala Dataframe with array Struct

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, struct

I am having the spark data frame with Array of Struct. The structure of the dataframe is:

```
root
|-- recs: array (nullable = true)
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | |-- key: string (nullable = true)
| | |-- value: binary (nullable = true)`
```

The data in the dataframe is like this

```
[{id, 123}, {source, test1}, {type, aa}, {subType, xy}, {createTs, 2022-10-31T10:36:34.951Z}, {requestTrackingId, trackId}, {locationId, 5560}] [{id, 345}, {source, test2}, {type, ab}, {subType, xyz}, {createTs, 2022-10-29T10:36:34.951Z}, {requestTrackingId, trackId2}, {locationId, 55603}]
```

The output should look like this:

```
2022-10-31T10:36:34.951Z 
2022-10-29T10:36:34.951Z
```

Please provide the code snippet for this.

Comment: What have you tried until now? Show us what you've tried/searched/researched. And also, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help us to keep this website of high quality!

Comment: I have executed the below statement
df3.select($"recs".getItem(4)).show(2,false)
I got the results
{createTs, 2022-10-31T10:36:34.951Z}
{createTs, 2022-10-29T10:36:34.951Z}

When I am executing the below command to get the timestamp alone. I am getting the error message
df3.select($"recs".getItem(4).$"value").show(2,false)
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but string literal found.